# Python: getting AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'classes_' when tryig to use predict

Tags: python, twitter, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict demographic attributes from Twitter using LogisticRegression but I'm getting "File "Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 341, in predict
    return self.classes_[indices]
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'classes_'"

The Code:

```
_predictor = Predictor()
pred = _predictor.predict_attribute(_model_dir, attr, tweetsArr, _sent_vocab_file, _emo_vocab_file)



class Predictor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1.0, dual=False, penalty='l2', tol=1e-6)
        self.hv = HashingVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), binary=True)
        self.pred_classes = []
        self.pred_probs = []



def predict_attribute(self, dir, attr, tweets, sent_vocab_file, emo_vocab_file):
    pred_dict = {}
    # loading pre-trained model
    current = os.getcwd()
    if dir not in os.getcwd():
        os.chdir(dir)
        for file in glob.glob("*.pkl"):
            if attr in file:
                self.clf = joblib.load(file)
    pred_probs = self.clf.predict_proba(features).tolist()
    pred_classes = self.clf.predict(features).tolist()
    pred_dict['pred_probs'] = pred_probs
    pred_dict['pred_class'] = pred_classes
    return pred_dict
```

the full traceback:

```
C:\Users\orensig\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:315: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LabelEncoder from version pre-0.18 when using version 0.18.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.

UserWarning)
C:\Users\orensig\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:315: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from version pre-0.18 when using version 0.18.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.

UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Algo/streaming_tweets/Eugenia_predict_psycho-demographics_emotions.py", line 71, in predict_attribute

pred_classes = self.clf.predict(features).tolist()
  File "C:\Users\orensig\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 341, in predict

return self.classes_[indices]
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'classes_'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1585, in <module>

globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1015, in run

pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "Algo/streaming_tweets/Eugenia_predict_psycho-demographics_emotions.py", line 251, in <module>

prediction = pred.predict_attribute(model_dir, attr, tweets1, sent_vocab_file, emo_vocab_file)

File "Algo/streaming_tweets/Eugenia_predict_psycho-demographics_emotions.py", line 77, in predict_attribute

pred_dict['pred_class'] = pred_classes
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pred_classes' referenced before assignment

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you sure the models you load from the files are pre-trained? Can you test them separately? Also please post the full stack trace of error

Comment: @VivekKumar I added the full traceback above

Comment: Check your indentation on the last function.

Comment: @aryamccarthy The indentation is not the problem. The problem is return self.classes_[indices]
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'classes_'

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem derives from the fact that the model was trained with an earlier version than scikit-learn 0.18 and I don't know how to retrain the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need scikit-learn version 0.15:

`pip install 'scikit-learn==0.15'`